How do I include a static hql in other hql files?
I have multiple hql files that contain repeating initial code. So when I make changes to that bit of code, I have to change it in 12 files. I don't know if I'm using the wrong keyword search, but I am unable to find an answer. I have a concern that including it in the -i would cause the dynamic values in that code to be ignored as it contains the hive setup. Can you pass multiple -f paramaters? Is there a %include or anything? I'm familiar with including code in different languages, but not hql.
I do not want to do a $(cat file1.hql file2.hql) in the script, but if that's the only way, then I guess I have no choice, but that's not really a clean way to do it. Yes, I can build another hql file with that, but considering the number of users I have using my processes, that could become real messy real fast. I do have cleanup jobs for the logs and any data produced, and I could add that, but I really want something that is a lot less labor intensive.
Thanks for any help you can provide.

I figured it out! It's a wonderful thing to have a good night's sleep. So, if anyone else is having this problem, I was thinking about all the different ways to include static code from other languages and remembered cshrc uses 'source', so I tried it:
source /<path>/<hql filename>;
That's it. Stupid simple.
